Does Dispelling Globe counteract a spell that targets a creature inside the Globe?
While this previously seemed obvious to me, the answer to my previous question makes me doubtful.
Dispelling Globe (previously known as Globe of Invulnerability) has the following effect:

It attempts to counteract any spell from outside the globe whose area or targets enter into it, as if the globe were a dispel magic spell 1 rank lower than its actual spell rank.

My original interpretation was that any spell cast from outside the Globe, that enters the Globe, may get countered (with a counteract check).
But the wording implies that a spell such as Fire Ray, with no Area, isn't countered since its target (1 creature) isn't "entering" the Globe.

It does not stop spells from targeting a creature within
In case of spells like force barrage, as you say these target a creature, but the dispelling globe does not say it is counteracting targeting creatures within. It says that it is counteracting spells on a target that enters into the globe. Force barrage and similar attack spells do not typcially create an effect on their target that moves, they just cause damage, which once dealt is not a spell effect any more, so there is nothing to dispel or counteract, if the target then moves into the globe.
I found this a surprising result, because the predecessor of dispelling globe, globe of invulnerability in Pathfinder 1e and D&D did work differently, and blocked any spell effect of low enough level from working against creatures inside the globe or from entering the globe:

An immobile, faintly shimmering magical sphere surrounds you and excludes all spell effects of 3rd level or lower. The area or effect of any such spells does not include the area of the lesser globe of invulnerability. Such spells fail to affect any target located within the globe.

Apparently, that behavior has been changed in Pathfinder 2e.

RAI: Yes, it stops spells that enter into the globe
@NobodyTheHobgoblin's answer is correct RAW, per my reading. However, I think RAI (and the way I run it) strongly leans towards the dispelling globe trying to counteract any spell that enters into it. Three reasons:
Alternative meaning of "entering"
It's not the most direct rendering of the sentence (hence why I don't think this answer is RAW), but "It attempts to counteract any spell from outside the globe whose area or targets enter into it" could also be intended to mean "All spells that have a target or area that causes the spell to enter the globe are subject to a counteract attempt". Given the below reasons, I think that's likely what the designers intended and assumed - they might not have questioned their RAW meaning fully, as they been biased by the history and theme of the spell to arrive at this less straightforward interpretation.
History/Analogs
As Nobody the Hobgoblin's answer details, historically Globe of Invulnerability behaves with the RAI meaning I describe above. It also works that way in D&D 5e, the most popular fantasy TTRPG at the present, with popular video game adaptations even (such as Baldur's Gate 3). Everyone writing the rules text for dispelling globe is biased to assume that it works with the RAI interpretation, so it's easy for them to have assumed a less straightforward reasoning.
Thematic Reasoning
It makes little narrative sense that a spell that partially enters the globe via an area effect (or even entirely if the area if fully enclosed!), or enters the globe well after it has been cast (via the targets entering effect), would get counteracted while a spell that goes straight into the globe wouldn't. This also puts a point in favor the RAI interpretation.
TL;DR:
It seems pretty straightforward to conclude the designers mean to answer your question "yes", even if the most literal meaning of their words is "no", because there is a reasonably close alternative meaning of the sentence that aligns very strongly with the spell in similar RPGs and with the theme/narrative of the spell. Yes, it's not RAW, but very easily RAI; I run the spell as such and encourage all GMs to do the same.
